# get return value from codebehind from ajax function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to get value of currency from codebehind that then I call it using ajax, but I got nothing, it just show error, here the code

function js

```
  function showCRate2(obj) {
            var selectedCurrency = $('#<%=ddlPaymentCurrency.ClientID%>').val();
            console.log(selectedCurrency);
            if (selectedCurrency != null && selectedCurrency != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "TopUp.aspx/GetCRate",
                    data: '{id:"' + selectedCurrency + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var o = response.d;
                        $('#<%=hfCurrencyRate.ClientID%>').val(o.RateBuy);
                        $('#<%=hfCR.ClientID%>').val(o.RateBuy);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert('error')
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

and this the function in codebehind, return object(that later I need the value of it's RateBuy attribut (decimal)

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static OLServiceReference.CurrRate getCurr(int id)
{
    var CR = client.GetCurrRates(id);
            return CR;
    }
```

and these another related control

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPaymentCurrency" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"   onChange="showCRate2()"></asp:DropDownList>
<input type="text" id="hfCurrencyRate" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="" style="width: 230px" readonly="readonly" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCR" runat="server" /></div>
```

on calling showCRate2(obj) just error alert occured (error: function(response)) .I expect that form `hfCurrencyRate` show the Currency of Buy Rates. How to fix this? Any Idea?

Comment: Check browser's console window and see what error message it is displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method name in your AJAX call does not match the name of the method in your code behind:

```
url: "TopUp.aspx/GetCRate"
```

This requires a `static` ASP.NET AJAX Page Method to be named `GetCRate`, but you have this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static OLServiceReference.CurrRate getCurr(int id)
{
    var CR = client.GetCurrRates(id);
    return CR;
}
```

Either change the name of your server-side method to `GetCRate` or change the reference in your AJAX call:

```
url: "TopUp.aspx/getCurr"
```

Comment: @Ana - no problem, sometimes another set of eyes is all you need. Good luck to you.